# Rails 4 - set display value when editing autocomplete nested fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, simple-form, fields-for

I'm developing a form that links recipes, recipe_entries (has_many_though join table) and ingredients with jQuery autocomplete in Rails 4. I'm using a combination of of the simple_form, cocoon and rails4-autocomplete gems. The idea is that users can create a recipe and dynamically add and edit associated ingredients via autocomplete (the quantity for each ingredient is stored on the join table).

I have most functionality working, however the only issue that still bugs me is that I had to create an f.input for :ingredient that when editing the recipe shows values, such as the below image and not the desired name of the associated ingredient.

[image]

Other than that, I can dynamically create, delete and update all ingredient associations. Any tips are much appreciated. Here my code:

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem "cocoon"
gem 'rails4-autocomplete'
```

Recipe.rb

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :recipe_entries, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_entries

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_entries,:allow_destroy => true 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end
```

RecipeEntry.rb

```
class RecipeEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
end
```

Ingredient.rb

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :recipe_entries
    has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_entries
end
```

Recipes form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
  <% if @recipe.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@recipe.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this recipe from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @recipe.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <div id="recipe_entries">
      <%=  f.simple_fields_for :recipe_entries, :input_html => { :class => "form_inline" } do |entry|%>
          <% render 'recipe_entry_fields', :f => entry %>    
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add recipe entry', f, :recipe_entries%> 
    </div>
   <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

recipe_entry_partial

```
<div class="nested-fields">

    <% @it=f.options[:child_index] %>
    <%= f.input :ingredient_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {id: "ingredient_id#{@it}"} %>
    <%= f.input :ingredient, :url => autocomplete_ingredient_name_recipes_path, :as => :autocomplete, :input_html => {id_element: "#ingredient_id#{@it}"}, placeholder: "Enter ingredient..." %>
    <%= f.input :quantity %>

    <%= link_to_remove_association "remove entry form", f %>
</div>
```

**Update**
I believe that the easiest way of solving the edit display issue is to pre-insert the correct value in the f.input containing the autocomplete. e.g.

```
<%= f.input :ingredient, :url => autocomplete_ingredient_name_recipes_path, :as => :autocomplete, :input_html => {id_element: "#ingredient_id#{@it}", value: f.object.ingredient.name}, placeholder: "Enter ingredient..." %>
```

Unfortunate, this only works up to the recipe entries association. This means that I can still get values for e.g. f.object.ingredient_id which returns the correct result. However, I can't get the associated ingredient any more. I seem to be able to get the associated ingredient but when I try to e.g. call the .name method on it, I receive a nil error.

Strangely, I can get the ingredient_id by calling f.object.ingredient_id and can retrieve an Ingredient from the Model by calling e.g. Ingredient.get(1).name. BUT, I cannot dynamically link the two values. Ingredient.get(f.object.ingredient_id) returns a nil error. Also with to_string or to_integer calls.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the solution to a full autocomplete within the nested form is as follows:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <% @it=f.options[:child_index] %>
    <%= f.input :ingredient_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {id: "ingredient_id#{@it}"} %>
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :ingredients, f.object.ingredient do |ii| %>
            <%= ii.input :name, :url => autocomplete_ingredient_name_recipes_path, :as => :autocomplete, :input_html => {id_element: "#ingredient_id#{@it}"}, placeholder: "Enter ingredient..." %>
        <% end %>
    <%= f.input :quantity %>

    <%= link_to_remove_association "remove entry form", f %>
</div>
```

The trick was to place the f.input autocomplete within another fields_for tag and make sure to specify the context for each recipe_entry with a f.object.ingredient. Other than this partial, I didn't have to make any other changes!

Comment: This worked for me with nested_form_fields too, in case anyone else stumbles on this issue.